# How to make an abstract class member?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Let's say I have a class named `Foo` that is not supposed to be initialized. It must be inherited to be used. This makes `Foo` an *abstract class without pure virtual functions*.
I simplified it for the sake of example:

```
class Foo : Qwe
{
protected:
    Bar& bar;
    int baz;
    Foo(int baz_) : baz(baz_) {}
public:
    virtual void function_that_uses_bar() const override
    {
        // code that uses bar here
    }
}
```

Example of how `Foo` is used:

```
class Kappa : public Foo
{
public:
    Kappa() : Foo(10)
    {
        bar = Asd(); // Asd is a Bar
    }
}
```

So basically only classes derived from `Foo` know what should `bar` be set to.

The error I get: `Error C2530 'Foo::bar': references must be initialized` that refers to the `Foo`'s constructor.
How do I fix this?

Comment: `Bar& bar` is a reference so it must be initialized in the constructor's initializer list immediately before `baz`.

Comment: `Foo`'s constructor has to initialize `bar`. Typically that's done by passing a `Bar&` to the constructor.

Comment: You have a design bug. If only children of Foo know how to set `bar`, than `bar` does not belong to Foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before anything else, since you are in C++, there is no such thing as a *abstract class without pure virtual functions*. It simply is not a thing.

Then, your problem is that reference must be initialized. Look at this code:

```
Bar myBar;
Bar& bar; // Error

bar = myBar; // don't do what you think
```

Here, on the line where I commented "Error", it's because you can't delay the initialization of a reference. Reference are like an alias to another variable. Reference **must** be initialized with a value.

The line with the comment "don't do what you think" it's because it won't rebind the reference. It will call the function `Bar::operator=(const Bar&)`. It will make `bar` take the value of `myBar`.

Okay, with that explained, it will easier to understand what's going wrong in your class.

In your constructor, of `Foo`, there is hidden things going on.

Indeed, it will initialize `Foo::baz` with the value you got in the constructor, but it will also initialize other variables of your class, a bit like that:

```
//              implicit --v---v
Foo(int baz_) : baz(baz_), bar() {}
```

See the problem? You are initializing a reference iwth no variable to refer to. You need to refer a variable to be bound on.

Second problem, you are doing something wrong here:

```
Kappa() : Foo(10)
{
    bar = Asd(); // Asd is a Bar
}
```

You meant that `Asd` is a type that extends `Bar`? If so, you would change the instance `bar` to be the same value of an empty `Asd`. Yes, it will copy the content of the empty `Asd` to your `bar`. This is value semantics. User defined types are behaving just like fundamentals.

---

Okay, so now, how to fix that code?

I presume you want to create a *new instance* of a base class, and bind a reference to the parent to that new instance. If so, you need a variable that can live past the scope of the constructor:

```
Kappa() : Foo(10)
{
    Asd myAsd;
    bar = /* somehow bind bar to myAsd */

} // myAsd destroyed here!
```

As you can see, you must create a variable that must live past the `}`. The ideal would be a variable that live just long enough to stay alive as long as `Kappa` stay alive. Enter [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)!

Instead of a reference, that don't claim ownership, use `std::unique_ptr`. It's a class that represent a variable that is allocated on the free store, aka. a Heap allocated variable. It will behave similarly to an object in java or C# or *< insert managed language name >*. It is common to use `std::unique_ptr` alongside of `std::make_unique` for allocation.

You can use it like that:

```
class Foo : Qwe
{
protected:
    // pointer here, null by default
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar;

    int baz;

    Foo(int baz_) : baz(baz_) {}

public:
    virtual void function_that_uses_bar() const override
    {
        // code that uses bar here
    }
}

struct Kappa : Foo
{
    Kappa() : Foo(10)
    {
        // Create a new unique_ptr of Asd and bind it to bar
        bar = std::make_unique<Asd>(); // Asd is a Bar
    }
}
```